# MySQL php join 4 tables and match 2 of them on another column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables

**product, product_description, product_to_category, category_description**

Here are what my tables have as columns

**Product**

| product_id | model | quantity

---

**product_description**

| product_id | language_id | name | description

---

**product_to_category**

| product_id | category_id |

---

**category_description**

| category_id | language_id | name | description |

---

Can I join **product_to_category** with **category_description**  on **category_id** and how?

---

Here is my code so far and it works , I have joined 3 tables on their **product_id** but I can't join category_description because it doesn't have a **product_id**

The idea behind my code is to get the **name** row from **category_description**

---

```
<?php
    include '../config.php';
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = DB_USERNAME;
    $password = DB_PASSWORD;
    $database = DB_DATABASE;

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Category Connection


    //Product connection
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product,product_description,product_to_category 
            WHERE product.product_id = product_description.product_id 
            AND product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id
            AND product_description.language_id = 2";

    $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($product = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $product_name           = $product["name"];
            $product_category       = $product["category_id"];
            $product_id             = $product['product_id'];
            $product_description    = $product["description"];
            $product_model          = $product["model"];
            $product_price          = $product["price"];
            $product_image          = $product["image"];
            $product_qty            = $product["quantity"];

            echo $product_name . "<br>";
    }
}

/*Second connection*/
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, I've also used explicit joins instead of your implicit joins. Because I think this is best practice.

```
SELECT * FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN category_description cd ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id
WHERE pd.language_id = 2
```

Comment: What does  pd,ptc and cd mean?

Comment: These are called aliases from the table name.

Comment: Oh ok,so does my echo code change in any way? how do i echo the name of the category and the name of the product side they both have row "name"

Comment: In your select: `SELECT cd.name as category_name, p.name as product_name FROM .....` 

Then in your echo: `echo $product['category_name'];` and `echo $product['product_name'];`

Comment: Thanks for help,can you link me somewhere where i can read more on those stuff?

Comment: You're welcome. The best link I can give you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/

Comment: Btw the SELECT where do i put it in  here? SELECT * FROM the code that you posted in the comment

Comment: `SELECT cd.name as category_name, p.name as product_name, * FROM`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136449/discussion-between-innervisions-and-daan).

Comment: Specify each column name you will use in the script. This is a faster then a select * anyways

Comment: if i do this SELECT p.name as product_name FROM and try to echo it out as $product_name    = $product["product_name"]; nothing happens? any idea

Answer (score 1):

To join all 4 tables, below is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM product p
JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
JOIN product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
JOIN category_description cd ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id
WHERE pd.language_id = 2
```